# Pivot Unpivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the values below

```
ID Bal1 Bal2
A   10   20
B   30   40
C   50   60
```

I need output like below

```
ABal1 ABal2 BBal1 BBal2 CBal1 CBal2 
10      20   30    40     50    60
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] you post. Your problem can't be in both mysql and sql-server. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, but you should really think about the design...

Paste this into an empty SQL-Server query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID VARCHAR(1),Bal1 INT,Bal2 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('A',10,20)
,('B',30,40)
,('C',50,60);

    SELECT tblA.Bal1 AS ABal1
          ,tblA.Bal2 AS ABal2
          ,tblB.Bal1 AS BBal1
          ,tblB.Bal2 AS BBal2
          ,tblC.Bal1 AS CBal1
          ,tblC.Bal2 AS CBal2
    FROM @tbl AS tblA
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT Bal1,Bal2 FROM @tbl WHERE ID='B') AS tblB
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT Bal1,Bal2 FROM @tbl WHERE ID='C') AS tblC
    WHERE tblA.ID='A'
```